# Jira issue aggregrator for aggregating tickets from different servers

Tags: jira

At my work, I have projects that are tracked on different Jira servers, is there a software that I can use to show them together?

Answer (score 1):

**BoldBI** provides an end-to-end Business Intelligence Solution that is an option to consider. BoldBI has a JIRA integration by which you can work with data from multiple JIRA servers, https://www.boldbi.com/integrations/jira.

Sample JIRA dashboard: https://samples.boldbi.com/integrations/jira/issue-tracker-dashboard

**Steps to aggregate data from two JIRA servers in BoldBI from below,**

**Step 1:** Create a data source using BoldBI JIRA connector and import the data from your JIRA server 1, by referring to the following documentation https://help.boldbi.com/cloud-bi/working-with-data-source/data-connectors/jira/.

**Step 2:** Create another data source with JIRA server 2, the same way did in Step 1.

**Step 3:** Open the Data Sources tab click on Combine Data Source.
[image]

**Step 4:** In the combine data source window, select the two data sources which you need to combine. Click append”. This will join the two data sources row-wise, so it will have both servers’ data.

Reference: https://help.boldbi.com/embedded-bi/working-with-data-source/combine-data-sources
[image]

**Step 5:** Now you can create dashboards and see insights of data from different JIRA servers. In dashboard designer, click the “use existing” option to import the combined data source for doing the dashboard.

**Step 6:** Now the combined data source will have the data from two servers. Use the combined data source for doing the dashboard.
[image]

**Note: I work for Bold BI.**